# Send email via gmail from VBA (MS Access) with CDO: The Transport Failed to connect to the Server

Tags: vba, gmail, cdo.message

I found following code but it is not working.

```
Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.message")
With cdomsg.Configuration.Fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 465
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = MailSender
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = MailPassword
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxyserver") = "xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080"
    .Update
End With
' build email parts
With cdomsg
    .To = MailTo
    .From = MailSender
    .Subject = MailSubject
    .TextBody = MailText
    .Send
End With
    Set cdomsg = Nothing
```

I get the error

```
The Transport Failed to connect to the Server
```

I'm behind a proxy I tried with and without it. The error is the same. What I'm uncertain about is if IIS is required for this to work becasue when googling this error it's often about issues with ASP and IIS. I think the code is fine. It' s identical to code working for others.

Other potential issues?

EDIT:

Is there a tool which allows me to get a for meaningful error message?

EDIT:

Never got this to work. Company changed to gmail as email provider and I did not get it to work either with my private gmail (proxy issues?) or my company email now linked to gmail ("Google Business"). However company has licensed [Affixa](https://www.affixa.com/) chrome plugin. With that plugin it is possible do send email or better said affixa will open a dialog in gmail and you will have to press send manually.

Comment: Considered setting the time out a bit longer than 10?

Comment: Doesn't matter. &0 result in same error. Set it lower so I don't have to wait forever when testing a different "version" of code.

Comment: Have you tried running the code on a machine which is not behind a proxy (such as you personal computer)?

Comment: Try port 587 instead of 465, I use that in my code !

Comment: Tried both ports, same error.

Comment: See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833   this gives info about how google two step verification of user login effects the above.  You need to use a specially generated "app password" instead of your usual gmail password